# How optimize the update of a C# dictionary with a single key lookup?

Tags: c#, performance, dictionary, optimization

Say for example I have:

```
Dictionary<string, double> foo;
```

I can do:

```
foo["hello"] = foo["hello"] + 2.0
```

Or I could do:

```
foo["hello"] += 2.0
```

...but the compiler just expands this to the code above. I verified that by using JetBrains .Peek to look at the assemblies.

This seems wasteful as two key lookups are required to update. Is there a dictionary implementation that can do this in one lookup? Note I'm using a dictionary to store 100k items of geometry information from a mesh and the lookups are in an inner loop. Please no *"premature optimization is the root of all evil"* answers. :)

Yes I have profiled.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What are you storing in the dictionary, if it's a class (well, reference type more precisely) then store that object and use that rather than looking up twice: `var hello = foo["hello"]; hello.foo =+ hello.foo`

Comment: The object stored is a pair of integers. I made it a struct because it ``should``?? not generate so much GC pressure. I'm easily generating 100k + objects very fast. I can try it as a class and see what happens.

Comment: In that case I'm not sure how you could do it. Whatever structure you use will have to: 1) get the struct out. 2) Alter it (creating a new one) 3) Put it back in. I think steps 1/3 are unavoidable. If it was a reference you could: 1) Get it out. 2) Alter it (changing/updating the reference that the dictionary points to).

Comment: To avoid GC pression if changing to use a class you could try to re-use instances, but that's a different question.

Comment: I guess what dictionary is missing is the ability to return a direct reference to the location which you can use to access/update directly.  For example  ``Reference<T> ReferenceFor(T key)`` where Reference is a class with a single property T Value {public get;public set}`.

Comment: That makes sense. What you want then, is to store a (custom made) `Reference<MyStruct>` class in your dictionary. The `Reference<T>` class would just have one field/property which was the value type to store. Be careful of GC because obviously when you populate the dictionary initially you'll be creating lots of `Reference` instances.

Comment: Yeah but then I'd need 100k instances of Reference defeating the purpose of using structs for values in the first place :) I'll just change to a reference and reprofile. It won't be as bad as I think. I'm sure.

Answer (score 3):

Using a class would probably be faster as the comments mention because:

With a struct, you must do a double look-up as mentioned in the comments.

With a class, you simply go to the memory of the class reference and can update it there.

Each Lookup:

- GetHashCode
- Get the bucket
- Iterate through to find the right one
- (This all involves reading multiple ref object values)

However, if you use a class and update its value:

- Change the value at the correct position relative to that ref.

It's a single change in memory.

@George Duckett's solution should be much faster. Change to a class and get the ref and update the object's value:

```
var hello = foo["hello"]; 
hello.howAreYou += 2.0;
```

By the way, this is an example case where a mutable class will win in performance over the immutable struct.

Comment: By the way, every time I use a struct I end up regretting it. (Hey, a struct would be more efficient... a few days later after an hour debugging a weird bug... Why did I use a struct again?!?)

Comment: Are the bugs you mention due to mutable fields on your structs. I've never run into bugs with immutable structs.

Comment: Yes, mutable structs are the biggest problem. Immutable structs have a good use case, but an immutable class is just as easy.

Comment: Also, with structs, one cannot block the default constructor. So checking for Empty becomes a problem. With a class, one can simply not have a default constructor and then simply check for null. Also, a null value not checked will result in a quick NullReferenceException which is easy to debug. An Empty struct may cause much more difficult to find logic errors.

Comment: Ooooh null is evil. I use Maybe<T> whereever I really want to handle that :) Also I got a nice framework for Immutables with lenses and an undo stack https://gist.github.com/bradphelan/8685964 one day I'll share it when I can untangle it from my app

Answer (score 2):

There's a method in ConcurrentDictionary, [ConcurrentDictionary.AddOrUpdate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378664%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), that does what you want. You can update an existing value in the dictionary based on its previous value in one go.

However, the concurrent dictionary is supposed to be used in multiple thread situations, so I can imagine it does some locking which might defeat your optimization goal. But then again, you can always benchmark and see how it goes.

Comment: Sorry but this is no good. I looked at the source code for this method and it does ``at least`` two key lookups so it as least as bad as dictionary and most probably worse because of all the lock handling. Specifically it calls ``TryGetValue`` at least once and then ``TryUpdate`` at least once.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not. As noted in the comment by bradgonesurfing, the language lacks a way to return reference to the stored value, so when it has to change that value, it needs to find it again.

Also, you said you are storing pairs of integers. Did you thought about using an array? Even 100k long array is not even 1MB big. And I'm sure it would be fastest you can get.

Comment: It would be 100k * 100k as there could be 100k+ vertices and the key is an edge which is two vertices.

Comment: "It would be 100k * 100k" How? That doesn't make sense. If the index is index of edge and the the value in array is struct with 2 integers, then you only get 100k*2 ints.

Comment: I have vertices and triangles (provided from third party lib). The triangles have an index and the vertices have an index. I need to build an edge -> triangle mapping. The edge array does not exist yet. An edge is identified by the sorted pair of the vertex indices. An edge can map to 1 or 2 triangles. Therefore at least in the beginning as I iterate through triangles I need to be able to lookup edges using the sorted vertex indices pair to find a previous discovered edge. The algorithm is here https://gist.github.com/bradphelan/3c7a4e45e951c833badd if you are curious.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `TryUpdate` extension method for generic dictionaries, that does what you want. It is based on the advanced [`CollectionsMarshal.GetValueRefOrNullRef`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.collectionsmarshal.getvaluerefornullref) API (.NET 6+):

```
/// <summary>
/// Uses the specified function to update a key/value pair in the dictionary,
/// if the key already exists.
/// </summary>
public static bool TryUpdate<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> source,
    TKey key,
    Func<TKey, TValue, TValue> updateValueFactory) where TKey : notnull
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(source);
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(updateValueFactory);

    ref TValue valueRef = ref CollectionsMarshal.GetValueRefOrNullRef(source, key);
    if (Unsafe.IsNullRef(ref valueRef)) return false;

    valueRef = updateValueFactory(key, valueRef);
    return true;
}
```

The `key` is hashed only once, and the corresponding internal bucket is traversed only once also.

Usage example:

```
foo.TryUpdate("hello", (key, existing) => existing + 2.0);
```

The implementation above is a variant of the [`TryUpdate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72837813/how-to-update-the-value-of-a-key-in-a-dictionary-but-only-if-the-key-already-ex/72837894#72837894) posted by @GuruStron in an answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72837813/how-to-update-the-value-of-a-key-in-a-dictionary-but-only-if-the-key-already-ex) (includes benchmarks). The difference is that instead of a `TValue value` parameter, here the parameter is a function (`Func<TKey, TValue, TValue> updateValueFactory`).

Notice the similarity with the [`ConcurrentDictionary<K,V>.AddOrUpdate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.addorupdate) API:

```
public TValue AddOrUpdate(
    TKey key,
    Func<TKey, TValue> addValueFactory,
    Func<TKey, TValue, TValue> updateValueFactory);
```