# How to update the value of a key in a dictionary, but only if the key already exists, without hashing the key twice?

Tags: c#, performance, dictionary, .net-6.0, hashcode

I have a [`Dictionary<string, decimal>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2) with a fixed number of entries, and I want to update many of its values frequently, but only for keys that already exist. If a key is not already in the dictionary, I don't want to add it, because my goal is to restrict the dictionary to a fixed size. So the code below (using the `set` [indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.item)) will not work for my needs:

```
dictionary[key] = newValue;
```

This code will update the value of the `key` if it's already there, or it will insert a new key/value pair if it's not. That's not what I want. So I wrote an extension method `TryUpdate` for the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` class, with the desirable behavior:

```
public static bool TryUpdate<TKey, TValue>(
    this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> source,
    TKey key, TValue value)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(source);
    if (!source.ContainsKey(key))
        return false;
    source[key] = value;
    return true;
}
```

Now my code works as expected:

```
dictionary.TryUpdate(key, newValue);
```

What I don't like to the above implementation is that if the key already exists, which is the common case in my scenario, the key will be hashed twice in each `TryUpdate` operation. So in order to get the guarantee that my dictionary will not grow beyond its initial size, I am going to pay a doubled price in terms of performance. The keys are long strings, so the hashing cost is significant. Is there any way to rewrite my `TryUpdate` method, so that it is as performant as the `set` indexer?

Comment: Would it be an option to wrap the `decimal` in a reference type and then use `TryGetValue` followed by an update of the enclosed value?

Comment: @KlausGütter ideally I wouldn't like to do that, because it will certainly add a little bit of overhead. But in case there is no other option, I might consider it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since .NET 6 there is no need to use wrappers - use [`CollectionsMarshal.GetValueRefOrNullRef`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.collectionsmarshal.getvaluerefornullref?view=net-6.0) instead:

> Gets either a reference to a `TValue` in the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` or a reference `null` if it does not exist in the dictionary.

```
var x = new Dictionary<string, string>{{"test", "1"}};
ref var valueRefOrNullRef = ref CollectionsMarshal.GetValueRefOrNullRef(x, "test");
if (!Unsafe.IsNullRef(ref valueRefOrNullRef))
{
    valueRefOrNullRef = "2";
}

Console.WriteLine(x["test"]); // prints 2
```

**UPD**

Full implementation:

```
public static bool TryUpdate<TKey, TValue>(
    this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> source,
    TKey key,
    TValue value)
    where TKey : notnull
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(source);
    ref var valueRefOrNullRef = ref CollectionsMarshal.GetValueRefOrNullRef(source, key);
    if (Unsafe.IsNullRef(ref valueRefOrNullRef))
    {
        return false;
    }

    valueRefOrNullRef = value;
    return true;
}

var x = new Dictionary<string, decimal> { { "test", 1 } };
Console.WriteLine(x.TryUpdate("test", 2)); // True
Console.WriteLine(x.TryUpdate("test1", 2)); // False
Console.WriteLine(x["test"]); // 2
Console.WriteLine(x.ContainsKey("test2")); // False
```

Note that this approach has next limitation (compared to the wrapper one):

> Items should not be added or removed from the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` while the `ref TValue` is in use.

**UPD2**

Just for the funsies created a [small benchmark](https://gist.github.com/gurustron/f2207240878bba758cbecdd1fb26e3d1) (not ideal of course, it heavily misses at least on the string and dictionary size variance) but it seems that even for small dictionaries and small/medium string lengths approach with single access by key is faster:

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BothUsingCollectionsMarshal | 204.92 ns | 2.008 ns | 1.677 ns |
| BothUsingDoubleAccess | 355.74 ns | 5.947 ns | 6.107 ns |
| OnlyPresentUsingCollectionsMarshal | 116.19 ns | 2.225 ns | 2.081 ns |
| OnlyPresentUsingDoubleAccess | 271.66 ns | 5.423 ns | 5.326 ns |
| OnlyMissingUsingCollectionsMarshal | 91.20 ns | 1.851 ns | 1.818 ns |
| OnlyMissingUsingDoubleAccess | 94.78 ns | 1.891 ns | 2.524 ns |

Answer (score 2):

The following approach avoids the double hashing at the cost of an additional indirection. The idea is to wrap the `decimal` in a reference type and then use TryGetValue followed by an update of the enclosed value. This will also work with older .NET versions than .NET6.

```
class WrappedDecimal
{
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
}

Dictionary<string, WrappedDecimal> dict;

// update
if (dict.TryGetValue(key, out var v) 
{
    v.Value = newValue;
}

// read
if (dict.TryGetValue(key, out var v) 
{
    return v.Value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Klaus! I'll probably go with GuruStron's [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72837894/11178549), but I'll keep your idea in mind!

Comment: I would argue about possibly making `WrappedValue<T>` class for convenience.

Comment: @GuruStron I would argue for using the existing [`StrongBox<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.strongbox-1). :-)

Comment: @TheodorZoulias even better!