# Is there a way to implement a TryGet function that works on ref structs?

Tags: c#, dictionary, c#-11.0

Right now, I have two functions that go together:

```
bool HasX(int key) { ... }
ref S GetX(int key) { ... }  // S is a struct
```

They work, but when I need to check for existence before calling the get function, it needs to calculate the offsets into the arrays and check values twice. This is exactly why functions like `Dictionary<TK, TV>.TryGetValue(TK key, out TV value)` exist, so only one lookup is necessary.

Things I've tried to combine them into one:

```
// ref S here has different semantics, I'm not able to set it to a ref structure handle
bool TryGetX(int key, ref S value)

// out S here has different semantics, it's a value copy for structs
bool TryGetX(int key, out S value)

// ref S here has different semantics, I'm not able to set it to a ref structure handle
bool TryGetX(int key, ref S value)

// copy again rather than reference
S? TryGetX(int key)

// equivalent to ref Nullable<S>, not Nullable<ref S>, so again not suitable
ref S? TryGetX(int key)

// this works, but it's backwards from normal, and I'm unable to write it cleanly 
// as a condition, like: if(dict.TryGetValue(key, out var value)) { /* use value here */  }
ref S TryGetX(int key, out bool found)

// perhaps the cleanest so far, and return Unsafe.NullRef<S> for failure. 
// still not idiomatic though
ref S TryGetX(int key)
```

Is there a way to write a traditional `TryGet` function for `ref` structures?

Comment: @pm100 does it work with ref structs?

Comment: It does not, I also considered that, you can't modify generic arguments with `ref`.

Comment: You are trying to challenge the very nature of `ref struct`. Sometimes when I get hit by such situations, I reconsider my design rather than going around the language design.

Comment: That is quite the strong claim that I'm trying to challenge the very nature of `ref struct`. Given that I already have the `Has..`/`Get..` code working, how is trying to merge them into one function call, like every other collection in C# that allows structured keys, going against anything?

Comment: Have you considered having `HasX` and `GetX` as methods in a class, together with any (mutable) fields you may need to persist results calculated by `HasX`, so that `GetX` can reuse them? It's not directly answering your question, but it might get the job done, and in an OO way. TryGet functions with their 'by reference' parameters feel like a remnant of the old VB6 procedural paradigm.

Comment: Asking because I haven't seen code like this before: what is the use-case for this? If you consistently want to get the struct by ref, doesn't that indicate that you want a class instead?

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72837894/2501279) answer

Comment: @RuudHelderman, unless I'm misreading that, aren't you suggesting that the `Has*` method do more than it's supposed to do, especially since the extra work is warranted only on half the results that may or may not even be used? That's a pretty bad failure of SOLID principles.

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev, "If you consistently want to get the struct by ref, doesn't that indicate that you want a class instead" -- no, it doesn't. And, with all due respect, the fact that you can't imagine a use case for a getter suggests that perhaps this isn't a question you should be commenting on in the first place.

Comment: @Blindy Quoting OP (emphasis mine): "it needs to calculate the offsets into the arrays and check values __twice__." This suggests you have identified _some_ calculation that is required by _both_ methods. So let the calculation be performed by the first method that needs it (`HasX`), and save the result so that the second method (`GetX`) can benefit from it too. I never said `HasX` should perform actions that are only required by `GetX`. It's easier to explain with code, but I'd need to see the implementation of `HasX` and `GetX` for that.

Comment: First off, you don't need to call them in pairs, if you know the key exists (the common case) then you call `Get` directly. Second, what exactly are you saving here? What if the structures have changed between calls? The backing storage for the elements is a resizable array (`List<>`), so simply inserting items can invalidate your references. That's *why* I want one call, so the calculation is "atomic". "It's easier to explain with code" -- no, I really don't believe it is, because as soon as you start writing your code you'll realize the mess of allocations you're creating in a zero-alloc env

Comment: @Blindy A "__resizable__ array" in a "__zero-alloc__ env". That's ironic. Please note the class I proposed may well be a singleton, and it would save only the last found struct; is that zero-alloc enough for you? Give it two getters, one self-sufficient, the other intended to immediately follow `HasX`. Use private methods to avoid code duplication. "The calculation is _atomic_." That's ironic too; `List<>` is not thread-safe.

Comment: The quotes around atomic are to mean atomic in the sense of "one operation", this has nothing to do with threading, you just randomly brought it up. You can also resize arrays just fine in a zero-alloc environment, zero-alloc doesn't mean no allocations, it means the literal minimal number of allocations possible. If you need to alloc something, you do. And your suggestion... static structures that stick around and may or may not affect how future calls behave? Personally I'd fire you on the spot, but you seem to know what you're doing, so I'm sure you'll be fine!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want inspiration from the runtime, [`CollectionsMarshal.GetValueRefOrNullRef`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.collectionsmarshal.getvaluerefornullref?view=net-6.0#system-runtime-interopservices-collectionsmarshal-getvaluerefornullref-2(system-collections-generic-dictionary((-0-1))-0)) (which gets a ref to an entry in an dictionary) returns `Unsafe.NullRef<TValue>()` if the entry wasn't found (which can be detected with `Unsafe.IsNullRef<TValue>()`).

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about `CollectionsMarshal` and such an interesting use of null references. Thanks!

Comment: I somehow missed that one as well, but I did consider the case, it's the last one on my list.  It really is the best way, isn't it. How unfortunate that it doesn't pattern match well at all :(

Comment: Yeah I know it's on your list. I'm not trying to suggest something you haven't thought of, just adding some weight in favour of that option

Comment: In the end I kept the `Has*` version as is, to quickly check for the existence of the key if that's all I care about at the call site, and I added a branch to return a null reference to the getter (instead of just crashing, as intentionally designed before) so I can call it directly and skip the check if I have actual work to do with the reference. No ABI changes, so that's a plus, but I'm still wishing they add a way to return `ref` structures as `out` parameters in the future!